# Debugging non-responsive python/PyQt application in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pyqt, pycharm

How do you go about debugging a non-responsive python/PyQt application in PyCharm?

I am an experienced programmer, but new to all thing python.  I have been given a large application (36,000 lines), which works under Windows, to port to Linux.

Having made just a handful of changes for OS-specific stuff, when I run the application it comes up with its main window.  But then after a few seconds it becomes dimmed, and when I close the window I am asked to confirm to end "the window is not responding".

(Aside: On a whim I decided to try running the app via `sudo`, and surprisingly it works fine.  I have tried doing `strace` running as root versus non-root, but I'm fairly sure there is nothing obvious in the way of file accesses/permissions etc. that differs.  This may be a clue, but just as likely to be a red-herring, e.g. if it's an "uninitialized variable".)

If I debug it inside PyCharm, at that point I expect to click the "Pause Program" button, so that I can get a trace back and begin to see where it is in the code, and start stepping or whatever.  However, that button does nothing at this stage?  Maybe it only "works" when on "a python instruction"?

If I force a core dump (from the keyboard) and examine with `gdb`, I can see that the stack frame shows it is way down inside `libQtCore`/`libQtGui`, in `processEvents` on a call to `read`.

So how do I begin to go about debugging why it is (presumably) busy doing something at this point, or at least not responding?  Any tips would be welcome.  I do hope this question will not fall foul of SO's "too general" policy, any tips to get someone going on debugging a "non-responsive" program would be welcome.

Comment: Your GUI is frozen/non-responsive? Remove all non-GUI stuff like loading of resources, processing of data, ... from the PyQt thread. While doing this you may observer one of these things taking very long.

Comment: @Trilarion Don't know what this means.  Yes the GUI is non-responsive/frozen, and has to be forced to quit.  (Unless run as root, in which case it works fine.)  There are no separate threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, since no responses seem to be forthcoming.

In this case, the problem turned out to lie in a file which is **import**ed into other files, named `pyperclip.py`.  That had code outside of any function, and in a path through the source executed under Linux but I think not under Windows, which included:

```
app = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication([])
cb = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
```

Clearly some attempt to gain a clipboard object.  For whatever reason, this appears to work when run as **su**, but when run as the logged on user it causes the whole application to "hang".  Removing those two lines solved the unresponsiveness.

In terms of what I learnt from this for debugging unresponsive applications: you need to debug not from the entry point of the program, as I would have expected, but rather right from the start of each file, and actually step into each **import** line just in case it is executing some initial code.  Horrible!